# SpriteKit game on macOS: "Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution."

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, sprite-kit, metal

I'm running into a strange intermittent bug on a game I'm developing for iOS and macOS using SpriteKit. After launching on the Mac and waiting some random amount of time, the game window starts flickering (see below) and I start getting the following console errors:

```
2016-10-20 12:52:43.000352 RobotGame-macOS[27086:790757] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. <private>
2016-10-20 12:52:43.000432 RobotGame-macOS[27086:790757] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. <private>
2016-10-20 12:52:57.139097 RobotGame-macOS[27086:790803] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. <private>
2016-10-20 12:52:57.139173 RobotGame-macOS[27086:790803] Execution of the command buffer was aborted due to an error during execution. <private>
```

[image]

I've currently designed all the graphics using basic SpriteKit SKNodes with no other custom shaders or any other advanced Metal stuff.

So what is causing this? I don't know where to begin with debugging it.

Comment: This sounds like a bug. I'd recommend [filing a Radar](http://bugreport.apple.com), describing this problem and attaching a copy of your project if possible.

Comment: Agree with @warrenm, this is probably something to do with z-space fighting or something much more problematic in the rendering Apple does. a workaround might be to clearly delineate your "layers" by manually setting zPositions as appropriate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with z-fighting.

Comment: Hmm, could you provide your project?  I would love to have a look and see if I can come up with where things went wrong

Comment: I'm not comfortable posting my project. Can I send it to you? What's traditionally done here on StackOverflow?

Comment: You can just email it to me knight0fdragon@gmail.com

Comment: @Knight0fDragon: sent.

Comment: I have a sprite kit chat on here if you do not want to flood the chat

Comment: Facing the exact same Problem. How you resolve it?

Comment: @vanshika: I never did resolve it, and instead abandoned SpriteKit altogether. I hope you have better results.